# Editing multiple rows in a table (updating multiple records)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a list of payment records in Payments#index. I've been asked to make that table directly editable and to have one button that saves all the updates. So far I've only partially managed to do this by wrapping each row around a form_for for that record like so:

```
  <tbody>
    <% @payments.each do |payment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= payment.client.trading_name %></td>
        <td><%= payment.date_of_payment %></td>
        <td>
          <%= form_for payment do |f| %>
              <%= f.text_field :amount %>
              <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'table_submit' %>
          <% end %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= form_for payment do |f| %>
              <%= f.select :sequence_type, options_for_select(%w[RCUR OOFF FRST FNAL]) %>
              <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'table_submit' %>
          <% end %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul>
            <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_payment_path(payment) %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Destroy', payment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Is it possible to be able to edit all the records then have one update button instead of having to save each record individually? If so, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible: 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple-revised 
And old version 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple

Comment: Thank you, I'll check those videos.

Comment: I've watched the video and this seems to be exactly what I need. Thank you again :)