# How to generate a form that edit and creates all the records of a model in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, actionpack

I have a model that stores template data and is independent with other models. I want to construct a form where I can view all the records of that model, edit them, delete them and also create a new records. Since rails form helper requires a record, is there any way to achieve my requirement or do I have to write the form manually and handle the deleted records and new records with js ?

Comment: Have you looked at [this questions answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850553/editing-multiple-rows-in-a-table-updating-multiple-records)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing multiple rows in a table (updating multiple records)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850553/editing-multiple-rows-in-a-table-updating-multiple-records)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to iterate over all our records and then render a form for each record in itself. Here is how you might do that:

```
# resource/index.html.erb
// all existing records
<%= render partial: "form", collection: @all_resource_records, as: :resource %>

// new record
<%= render partial: "form", locals: { resource: ResourceModel.new } %>
```

-

```
# resource/_form.erb
<%= form_for resource do |f| %>
  // ... form fields ...
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I do not want to submit the form every time for every records I have changed. This is creating unwanted forms for every record.